# Masking sprites in cocos2d for android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I want to develop a game like jigsaw where the player will attach pieces of puzzle to match to a sprite.For this I've figured out to do Masking. I even found one class in cocos2d for iphone named CCMask that does this task pretty well. However when I try to port this to the java code for use with cocos2d-android I get Null pointer exception at CCRenderTexture. The class that I am trying to port is [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/ccmask-for-cocos2d/).

Somewhere I read that if I do CCRenderTexture under the layer's onEnter callback the code will not crash and it doesn't crash when I do it like that. But then I don't get any masked sprite either as I have to add the CCMask class as a child to a layer to call the onEnter method.

Can anybody help me with the proper flow of the code or by confirming that it really works for cocos2d-android? [This](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/) is the link for the library that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `cocos2d-android` development stopped a time ago (according to your link, last port is for `cocos2d-iphone 0.99.4`), so if you're working with cocos2d 1.x or higher, chances are that cocos2d-android won't work as you expect.

For android game development, I'd highly recommend [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which still lets you develop natively in java. Anyway, if you want a more straightforward conversion from your current project, [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) is also a great option.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the info. I'd like to know which one is better of two in terms of online resources and ease of use.Is masking possible by AndEngine also?The game might involve interaction at native side for in-app purchases and social sharing.

Comment: Both LibGDX and cocos2d-x have a vast community (maybe cocos2d-x's is a little bigger). Regarding ease of use, it all depends on which language are you more confortable with: cocos2d-x is c++ based and LibgGDX is written in Java. I'm guessing that if you have a working cocos2d-iphone project, the easiest choice for you would be cocos2d-x, since you'll only need to 'translate' objective-c to c++. Finally, I don't think you'll find big problems to integrate native features with any of them.